# Gerar PDF com pdflatex

Tags: pdf, latex

Estou tentando gerar meu pdf mas estou tendo dificuldades, segue as imagens com os erros encontrados

[image: Terminal]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

A mensagem

```
! Latex Error: File `titlesec.sty' not found.
```

informa que o pacote `titlesec` está sendo pedido no preâmbulo do documento e não está instalado. Retire ele apagando a linha

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
```

ou, caso tu tenha privilégios de administrador, instale-o com o comando

```
sudo tlmgr install titlesec
```

Comment: dentro do meu arquivo sbc-template.sty tem um linha "\RequirePackage{titlesec}", eu apaguei, mas aew nem no overleaf compilou

Comment: Eu baixei o sbc-template disponível em [https://github.com/uefs/sbc-template-latex](https://github.com/uefs/sbc-template-latex) e deu tudo certo. [Aqui tem uma screenshot provando isso](https://imgur.com/a/RzTf56L). Recomendo baixar de novo o template, rodar o comando que passei na resposta e aí editar o arquivo `sbc-template.tex` que vem como exemplo.